# How to sql sum from another joined table calculation result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I neeed to do sum in my query with the calculation result from another table.

```
Budget table :

Field           |Type                     |Null|Key|Default |Extra         |
----------------+-------------------------+----+---+--------+--------------+
id              |bigint(20) unsigned      |NO  |PRI|        |auto_increment|
section         |varchar(255)             |NO  |   |        |              |
purpose         |varchar(255)             |NO  |   |        |              |
curr            |varchar(3)               |NO  |   |        |              |
qty             |int(11)                  |NO  |   |        |              |
price           |double(20,10)            |NO  |   |        |              |

Improvement Table :

Field         |Type               |Null|Key|Default |Extra         |
--------------+-------------------+----+---+--------+--------------+
id            |bigint(20) unsigned|NO  |PRI|        |auto_increment|
budget_id     |bigint(20) unsigned|NO  |MUL|        |              |
reduced_qty   |int(11)            |NO  |   |        |              |
reduced_price |double(20,10)      |NO  |   |        |              |
```

Simple mathematics calculation would be like this :

```
(qty - total_reduced_qty) x (price - total_reduced_price)
```

the relation budgets has many improvements, so i need to sum the improvements first before subtract them with budgets.qty and budgets.price

What i've tried so far :

```
Budget::leftJoin('improvements', 'budgets.id', '=', 'improvements.budget_id')
    ->addSelect('purpose', 'section')
    ->addselect(DB::raw('SUM(improvements.reduced_qty) as total_reduced_qty'))
    ->addselect(DB::raw('SUM(improvements.reduced_price) as total_reduced_price'))
    ->addselect(DB::raw('SUM(((qty - total_reduced_qty) * (price - total_reduced_price))) as budget_total'))
    ->groupBy('section', 'purpose')
    ->get();
```

and got this error :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_reduced_qty'
```

How can i achieve this ?

update 1 :

as suggested by Akina, i tried raw sql queries :

```
select
  `section`,
  `purpose`,
  SUM(
    (
      qty - (
        select
          sum(reduced_qty)
        from
          `improvements`
        where
          `improvements`.`budget_id` = `budgets`.`id`
      )
    ) * (
      price - (
        select
          sum(reduced_price)
        from
          `improvements`
        where
          `improvements`.`budget_id` = `budgets`.`id`
      )
    )
  ) as total
from
  `budgets`
group by
  `section`,
  `purpose`;
```

However as not all of the budgets have improvement(s) i've got the null result for them :

```
+------------+------------------------+----------------+
| section    | purpose                | total          |
+------------+------------------------+----------------+
| ACCOUNTING | GENERAL-IMPROVEMENT    |           NULL |
| ACCOUNTING | GENERAL-INCIDENTAL     |           NULL |
| ACCOUNTING | GENERAL-ROUTINE        |           NULL |
| ACCOUNTING | PRODUCTION-IMPROVEMENT | 500.0000000000 |
| ACCOUNTING | PRODUCTION-PROJECT     |           NULL |
| ACCOUNTING | PRODUCTION-ROUTINE     |           NULL |
+------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

if they don't have improvements , they should reslting original amount / qty instead of null,
How to solve this ?

Comment: Use exact columns instead of alias column or use subquery

Comment: You cannot use the output alias of one output expression-1 in the expression-2 for another output column. Use expression-1 instead of this alias in expression-2.

Comment: @RahulBiswas do you mean i need to create another column inside improvements table to sum them up ? i personally avoid that because the data is very dynamic. But for subquery i agree it might work, just not sure how to do that tbh

Comment: From the other side, you try to construct an expression which uses SUM of SUM - this is not allowed.

Comment: @Akina i see, hence as suggested by Rahul Biswas i need to use exact columns

Comment: @Akina so this operation is not possible then ?

Comment: Your "simple calculations" (which is a fragment of SQL code) and "i've tried so far" (which is laravel code) have close to nothing in common.

Comment: @Akina actually that isn't sql, its simple mathematics just adding the dot (sql like) to make it easier to read, but well i revised it so it just mathemathics now

Comment: Sum of Sums needs in separate grouping for each Sum, hence you need in subquery which sums the inner Sum. I recommend you to build raw SQL firstly and, when it will give correct output, convert it to laravel code.